# Algorithm to compute the difference between a set of rectangles and a single rectangle

Tags: algorithm, rectangles, geometry-surface

Let's say I have a red rectangle with coordinates `(x,y)`, `(x1,y)`, `(x1,y1)`, `(x,y1)` which is overlapped by an undefined number of different blue rectangles (which may have different width and/or height) and are randomly positioned on a surface (they might even not overlap the red rectangle at all). Anyway, something like this:

[image]

I have the blue rectangles stored in an array of `rectangles` and I have the coordinates of each blue rectangle too.

Now, what I need to do is select the parts of the red rectangle which are not overlapped by any of the blue rectangles of the `rectangles` array (basically I need to do a difference between the `union` of all the blue rectangles and the red rectangle). In the previous example, these parts would be (delimited by a black border):

[image]

And also, I need to compute new rectangles from these parts and the result as an array. Therefore, the previous parts should became the following rectangles:

[image]

Or the following rectangles (it doesn't really matter how they are generated, of course as few as possible will be better (but looking at the following image I guess that there can't be less than `n` rectangles given the parts of it, they will always be `n`, where `n = 13` in this case (correct me if I am wrong))):

[image]

After that, I should return an array containing these rectangles created from the parts of the red rectangle.

So the requirements are:

- **If there aren't blue rectangles that overlap** the red rectangle, return an *array containing the red rectangle*;
- **If there are blue rectangles that overlap** the red rectangle, *compute the difference*, *get the parts which are not overlapped* by any of the blue rectangles and given these parts, *divide each part so that each part is formed by one or more rectangles*, *place all the found rectangles in an array* and return this array.

**Please note that we are not on a web page-like surface, meaning that `x < x1` like on the web (`left` < `right`), but `y > y1` (whereas on the web `top` < `bottom`), therefore I have the following `Rectangle` data structure (pseudo code) which has an `overlaps()` method:**

```
class Rectangle {
    this.x,
    this.x1,
    this.y,
    this.y1;

    /**
    * @constructor
    */
    Rectangle(x, y, x1, y1) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
    }

    /**
    * Tests whether this rectangle overlaps or is overlapped by the rectangle given as parameter.
    * 
    * @returns True if the rectangle is overlapped or overlaps the rectangle given as parameter, false otherwise.
    */
    Boolean overlaps(Rectangle rect) {
       compareX = function(coordX1, coordX2) {
          less = coordX1[0] > coordX2[0] ? coordX2: coordX1;
          greater = coordX1[0] > coordX2[0] ? coordX1: coordX2;
          return less[1] > greater[0] || less[0] == greater[0];

       }

       compareY = function(coordY1, coordY2) {
          less = coordY1[0] > coordY2[0] ? coordY2 : coordY1;           
          greater = coordY1[0] > coordY2[0] ? coordY1 : coordY2;
          return greater[1] < less[0] || greater[0] == less[0];
       }

       coordX1 = [this.x, this.x1]; // [] brackets create a new array
       coordX2 = [rect.x, rect.x1];
       coordY1 = [this.y, this.y1];
       coordY2 = [rect.y, rect.y1]
       return compareX(coordX1, coord) && compareY(coordY1, coordY2);
    } 
}
```

Now, what is an efficient way to compute the rectangles of the difference? (e.g. a `differenceRectangles` function)

```
    //...
    blueRectangles = [ blueRect1, blueRect2, blueRect3, ... ] // This is an array of blue rectangles, I don't know how many there are, but each item of the array is a `Rectangle` data structure with an `overlaps()` method
    redRectangle = new Rectangle(x, x1, y, y1);

    differenceRectangles = differenceRectangles(blueRectangles, redRectangle);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create condensed axes that contain only the relevant coordinates. For example the x axis should contain the `x` and `x1` of the outer rectangle plus all `x` and `x1` of all rectangles that lie in the big rectangle. Duplicate coordinates are merged.

You now have a grid of possible rectangles:

[image: condensed coordinate grid]

In this example, you get a 6×5 grid.

Iterate over all rectangles and mark the grid cells that they occupy as "holes". This can be done efficiently if the axes are sorted and if there is a dictionary to look up grid indices by coordinate. You get:

[image: occupied and empty cells]

Now combine the remaining rectangles. You could, foe example, join horizontally adjacent rectangles:

[image: first draft of solution]

There is room for improvement. It might be good to use one big rectangle for the big red area in the bottom right. But as a first draft, this should work.

Comment: So I should somehow flatten the `x`s and `y`s in an ordered array or array-like structure, take only the relevant ones (not those where there is an intersection of two or more blue rects) and then "scan" the red rectangle from  `x` to `x1` from left to right to see for areas not overlapped by a blue? Something like this? Anyway, why do you say `6x5` grid, isn't it a `6x6` in your example? How did you count the cells?

Comment: You have two independent axes, the horizontal axis for the x values and the vertical axis for the y values. When you treat a blue rectangle, find the grid that corresponds to (x, y) and (x1, y2) and fill everything in between.

Comment: You're right about the 6x6 grid. The upper image is missing a red line for the bottom of the right rectangle. Sorry about that, my MS Paint skills arent what they used to be. `:-)`

Comment: Thank you for the method, I am implementing it! If it works and I will be able to do it like you say, well just wait and I will accept the answer `;-)`. Thanks